# Mailer template render issue in outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, mailer

I have a mailer template which is built using divs. And the width of the mailer is 650px.
 It is showing perfectly in browsers but it is not taking width as 600px ion outlook, instead it has taken 100% width of the outlook view.

Also display:block is not forcing the span to take the full horizontal space available.

In short the template loads fine with browsers and thunder bird but collapsed in outlook.

here is my outer div structure

```
<div style="width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; font-family:  Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 16px">
....
</div>
```

And also How can I make it responsive to look good in mobile as well, if I fix the width as 600px how do we change it is small when it is views in mobiles?
Is it possible to us  media queries in mailer template also?

Comment: This is why eDM templates are built using tables.  Mail apps like Outlook don't follow the same rules as browsers.

Comment: @monners so you are suggesting to use tables instead of div?

Comment: I'd suggest using a eDM templating service, like Mailchimp.  Constructing eDM templates by hand is a pain in the a*s.  But failing that, yes.  Us tables.

Comment: I am not allowed to use custom templates right now. so i wil recreate it with tables. Do u have any idea about making it responsive?

Comment: I've not done it before, but it can be done (to an extent) by taking advantage of the fact that some mobile mail clients recognize 'display: block', and so will collapse block elements under each other in a smaller window.  Beyond that, you're on your own I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

First rule: Use Tables!

You should read this guidelines to HTML-Emails:

[Beginner Guide](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/20-email-design-best-practices-and-resources-for-beginners/)

[More Guides](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/ultimate-guide-html-emails/)